# TextOut to the center of Device Context

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

It frustrates me how difficult this is for me to figure out. I have an MFC application with a print feature. When I hit print I want to create a pdf file with a single word in the center of the A4 page. I am using a `CPrintDialog` and I actually managed to obtain my result *on my machine* (by hardcoding the coordinates for `TextOut`).

I want this software to work on any type of device context. My guess is that there has to be a way to get the logical coordinates (which `TextOut` expects) out of the `CDC`. I was playing around with `GetDeviceCaps` (with `HORZSIZE`, `HORZRES`, `LOGPIXELSX`, `ASPECTX`, `PHYSICALWIDTH`) but none of these values even gets close to my hardcoded values. The fact that the `y` coordinate I use is a **negative value** baffles me even more.
Is there a generic way to find the center of the device context?

Here are the values I see:

```
const int logPixY = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY); //600
const int logPixX = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX); //600

const int horzSize = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(HORZSIZE);  //216
const int vertSize = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(VERTSIZE);  //279

const int horzRez = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);    //5100
const int vertRez = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES);    //6600

const int pWidth  = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALWIDTH); //5100
const int pHeight = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALHEIGHT);//6600

const int aspectX = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(ASPECTX);    //600
const int aspectY = dcPrinter.GetDeviceCaps(ASPECTY);    //600
```

And the hardcoded `DrawText` that writes at the center of the page (kind of) is:

```
dcPrinter.TextOut(4200, -5000, L"Center");
```

Comment: Isn't the point of logical coordinates that you *don't* have to work with the device coordinates? Confused. It might help if you posted whatever you think is the best of your attempts.

Comment: @john This is my point. I don't know how to find the logical coordinates in a generic way. My hardcoded values don't give the same result on my friend's machine.

Comment: Been a while since I did any Win32 programming but don't `GetWindowOrg` and `GetWindowExt` get you those values?

Comment: There must be more to this as `PHYSICALWIDTH` and `PHYSICALHEIGHT` divided by 2 should be what you are looking for. But the numbers in your `TextOut` don't seem to come close. At that, it looks like you mapping with MM_LOENGLISH so hight and width should be 11000 and 8500 without margins.

Comment: So, my best guess, you are using `GetDeviceCaps` while still in the default MM_TEXT mapping mode and switched before print time.

Comment: @lakeweb You are absolutely right, my friend! Looks like `GetDeviceCaps` doesn't care about map mode, but I was indeed using `MM_HIENGLISH`. After switching to `MM_TEXT` I am able to write to the center of the page using `GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES) / 2` and `GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES) / 2`. Also positive y is down now so my other issue is fixed as well. I was not aware about map modes. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Ah, and thanks, I learned something. As I've never used anything but `MM_TEXT`, I did not realize that `GetDeviceCaps` is always in `MM_TEXT` mode. But it makes perfect sense in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

If using GDI it would be far easier to do centering via

```
SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_VCENTER|TA_VCENTER);
```

then simply use the page's center point (width/2, height/2) as the TextOut reference point. Let the TextOut API do the work of calculating the text's display area.

Comment: My issue is not with text alignment, but rather with finding the page's center point that you mentioned. I can't seem to find the width and height in a generic way.